# Example of distribution such that $f(F^{-1}(t) )=0$ for $t\in A$ where $A$ is set of positive measure.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider probability distribution with the pdf $f$ and quantile function $F^{-1}$.

I am looking to see if there is an example of distribution such that  the compositions
\begin{align}
f(F^{-1}(t)) =0
\end{align}
for $t \in A$ where $A$ is a set of positive Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$.

**Some thoughts:** Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f$ and $U$ be uniform random variable on $(0,1)$. Then, we know that $X=F^{-1}(U)$ and, hence,
\begin{align}
f(F^{-1}(U))= f(X)
\end{align}

Now, if the claim that $f(X)>0$ holds with probability one, then we are done and it shows that such a thing can not happen. However, while I think this is true, I am not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(f(X)=0)=P(X \in f^{-1} (0))=\int_{f^{-1} (0)} f(x)dx=0$ so $P(f(X)>0)=1$.